# Add name to the Address Book of the iphone

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

In the iphone app,I've a form with details such as name,address.
   I need to save the name,address in  the form to the iPhone AddressBook.Please someone help me  how to do this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ABAddressBookRef addressBook = ABAddressBookCreate();
ABRecordRef person = ABPersonCreate();

CFErrorRef error;
if (!ABRecordSetValue(person, kABPersonFirstNameProperty, @"John", &error))
{
   // error
}
if (!ABRecordSetValue(person, kABPersonLastNameProperty, @"Smith", &error))
{
   // error
}
if (!ABAddressBookAddRecord(addressBook, person, &error))
{
   // error
}
if (!ABAddressBookSave(addressBook, &error))
{
   // eror
}
```

You can set other properties with other `kABxx` constants.

Comment: Do not forget to ABAddressBookSave()